# How to average multiple variables in a dataframe grouped by date during certain time ranges in another dataframe

Tags: r

I am attempting to average data from several columns in a df based on times in another df, and grouped by date. df1 is a large object with >50,000 rows, has a datetime column, and multiple columns with data to be averaged during different periods of time. df2 has a column for date (which spans ~300 different dates), with sunrise, sunset, night midpoint, hour after sunset, and hour before sunrise. Since there are 5 different times in df2, I need averages within each period, making 4 averages for each variable in df1 for each date. I've pasted a couple of dput outputs below to simulate what types of dataframes I'm working with. Please note that since both dataframes are large, these are samples of each df and may not contain overlapping dates.

I've started by grouping by date, but I'm not sure how to proceed

```
df1<-structure(list(X = c(15255L, 370531L, 164052L, 385768L, 164660L, 320512L, 310332L, 207870L, 374209L, 384037L), datetime = structure(c(1382666832, 1491381288, 1428198714, 1496043810, 1428384762, 1476075474, 1472960394, 1441607022, 1492506756, 1495514124), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt" ), tzone = ""), mtr = c(476.100139098308, 40.3096980326816, 190.507994812417,
623.16297756071, 1316.10831568351, 130.05460789729, 426.391362627412, 794.871170055432, 664.854095538827, 87.0731714278365), vid = c(10.9712253212929, 0.348058462142944, 4.17660055086017,
14.7897213235497, 22.2240340709686, 2.94321962632239, 8.55752992630005, 13.4630692005157, 12.6897678971291, 3.3416459351778), vir = c(120.683479166031, 4.11496095843613, 45.9777652174234, 162.686932218075, 244.464374160767, 32.4128245811909, 94.1328294754028, 148.093760681152, 139.846099877357, 36.8101396411657 ), rtr = c(5237.10156184446, 443.406672837103, 2095.58784964886, 6854.79265188568, 14477.1914597946, 1430.60068747777, 4690.30499693279, 8743.58293390546, 7313.3949325189, 957.804907027068), mt = c(823746.117786614, 6359779.04662148, 1987510.62395236,
7445494.93388873, 2001143.65223585, 5856824.81619857, 5097032.76236516, 3010133.67082039, 6540792.26968181, 7415834.20122593), rt = c(9061207.29651591, 69957569.5237411, 21862616.8567079, 81900444.2763507, 22012580.1682171, 64425072.9831136, 56067360.3927196, 33111470.3731966, 71948714.979886, 81574176.2175404 ), ff = c(11.5323178782473, 32.1702791736536, 12.6389426556713, 11.5657282251475, 13.7768021406368, 12.2642003233716, 11.5373563882051, 15.652894576192, 14.1624290602428, 7.00239017068893), dd = c(203.263146323311, 149.347861521442, -3.54399807406384,
-28.6597226193563, 12.8977762014978, -0.544984261794743, -4.89316320474546, 7.7222011176437, -1.34222730712162, 67.3359470897316), u = c(-4.55474268125345, 16.401195526123, -0.781276245409457, -5.54700154345766, 3.07515145578288, -0.116652490502661, -0.984113817910801, 2.10328201280281, -0.331742766220023, 6.46166576572442 ), v = c(-10.5947475077281, -27.6753978729248, 12.6147722485071,
10.1487360422297, 13.4292114714994, 12.2636455333741, 11.4953082786785, 15.5109417311781, 14.1585431320976, 2.69821119162791), HGHT = c(992.029662282542, 500, 611.728202173514, 662.064284399711, 843.764907454437, 509.944907327361, 647.625056132299, 866.46899117831, 775.458469300207, 607.290800113246 )), row.names = c(6362L, 42544L, 15765L, 48247L, 16053L, 39092L, 35173L, 21715L, 44075L, 47609L), class = "data.frame") 

df2<-structure(list(datesrng = structure(c(1472774400, 1459555200, 1441411200, 1477699200, 1429315200, 1464393600, 1473984000, 1495411200, 1476576000, 1442620800, 1460505600, 1443657600, 1492473600, 1476144000, 1493424000, 1463443200, 1495065600, 1475971200, 1477008000, 1475020800 ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), sunset = structure(c(1472779582.28331, 1459560084.71692,
1441416180.73423, 1477699549.16032, 1429320925.56847, 1464401565.71724, 1473987905.57994, 1495418859.64555, 1476577281.2456, 1442624499.15826, 1460511088.26679, 1443660209.87386, 1492479354.40687, 1476145684.24286, 1493430380.23994, 1463450608.72453, 1495073049.53729, 1475973050.91342, 1477008900.89576, 1475023610.39393), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), sunrise = structure(c(1472816306.06605, 1459597800.89681,
1441453219.73769, 1477744025.10275, 1429356479.26218, 1464432397.8339, 1474026605.65712, 1495450223.82396, 1476620114.86204, 1442663516.23589, 1460547236.70363, 1443700908.94178, 1492514836.83256, 1476187853.56606, 1493464375.78259, 1463482440.55869, 1495104803.65952, 1476014950.67547, 1477052382.59468, 1475063997.46213), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt" )), day_length = structure(c(10.2010507620043, 10.4767166355583,
10.2886120717393, 12.3544284515911, 9.87602602958679, 8.5644768512249, 10.7500214392609, 8.71227178063658, 11.8982267867857, 10.8380771195889, 10.0412324573596, 11.3052966438399, 9.85622935738829, 11.7137008876933, 9.44320629100005, 8.8421761557791, 8.82058950755331, 11.6388227927685, 12.0782496998045, 11.2186300555203), class = "difftime", units = "hours"), hoursunrise = structure(c(1472812706.06605, 1459594200.89681, 1441449619.73769,
1477740425.10275, 1429352879.26218, 1464428797.8339, 1474023005.65712, 1495446623.82396, 1476616514.86204, 1442659916.23589, 1460543636.70363, 1443697308.94178, 1492511236.83256, 1476184253.56606, 1493460775.78259, 1463478840.55869, 1495101203.65952, 1476011350.67547, 1477048782.59468, 1475060397.46213), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), hoursunset = structure(c(1472783182.28331, 1459563684.71692, 1441419780.73423,
1477703149.16032, 1429324525.56847, 1464405165.71724, 1473991505.57994, 1495422459.64555, 1476580881.2456, 1442628099.15826, 1460514688.26679, 1443663809.87386, 1492482954.40687, 1476149284.24286, 1493433980.23994, 1463454208.72453, 1495076649.53729, 1475976650.91342, 1477012500.89576, 1475027210.39393), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), midpoint = structure(c(1472797944.17468, 1459578942.80687, 1441434700.23596,
1477721787.13154, 1429338702.41532, 1464416981.77557, 1474007255.61853, 1495434541.73476, 1476598698.05382, 1442644007.69708, 1460529162.48521, 1443680559.40782, 1492497095.61971, 1476166768.90446, 1493447378.01127, 1463466524.64161, 1495088926.59841, 1475994000.79445, 1477030641.74522, 1475043803.92803), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(182L, 122L, 64L, 239L, 18L, 177L, 196L, 292L, 226L, 78L, 132L, 90L, 258L, 221L, 269L, 166L, 288L, 219L, 231L, 208L), class = "data.frame")
```

For example, if I were only calculating averages for the column mtr in df1, the output would need: a date column, a 1st hour average mtr column, a 1st half average mtr column, a 2nd half average mtr column, and a last hour average mtr column.
I'm not really sure where to begin on code to calculate these averages. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of how your desired output would look like?

Comment: Sorry I haven't looked at this properly but at a glance I think maybe the zoo package might help, have you looked at that?

Comment: 'output<-setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol=9,nrow=0)),c("date","1st_Hour_mtr_Avg","1st_Half_mtr_Avg","2nd_Half_mtr_Avg","last_Hour_mtr_Avg", "1st_Hour_HGHT_Avg","1st_Half_HGHT_Avg","2nd_Half_HGHT_Avg","last_Hour_HGHT_Avg"))'

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out zoo